# How to I run salt command on Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, salt-stack

I'm trying to run a salt command through Python on my master 
I'm using Python subprocess to do this 
But when I write

```
subprocess.check_output(["salt", " '*' grains.item],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I get errors

Comment: Can you please post error also?

Comment: There's a typo or two in the code you posted. Does your real code look like that? We need to see the full error message, starting from the Traceback line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    out_bytes = subprocess.check_output(["salt"," '*' grains.item"],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['salt', " '*' grains.item"]' returned non-zero exit status 42

Comment: import subprocess

out_bytes = subprocess.check_output(["salt"," '*' grains.item"],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out_text = out_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print out_text
f= open("guru.txt","w+")
f.write(out_text)

Answer (score 1):

in salt grains.item (singular) needs an argument, what you probably want is grains.items which will return all grains assigned to the minion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess

subprocess.check_output(["salt-call", "'*'", "grains.item"])
```